# About ODR-violations and template variables

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, constexpr, one-definition-rule

I know that template functions don't suffer of multiple definitions when linking, like member functions defined inside a class, which are inline by default. Also, `constexpr` objects have internal linkage, but template variables have external linkage (I mean at namespace scope and for C++14 in both cases).

What about?

```
template<class T>
constexpr T i_am_odr_safe{};
```

Does `i_am_odr_safe` have external or internal linkage in C++14? and is it safe regarding multiple-definitions like function templates?

In other words, is `i_am_odr_safe` odr-safe?

Answer (score 10):

This is [core issue 1713](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1713), the direction of which IIRC is that this variable template will have external linkage.

And no, this hasn't been resolved yet, which is why LWG decided to plaster `inline` all over the variable templates in  the standard library when it adopted A+B2 of [P0604R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0607r0.html).