# How does template affect linkage of const global variable?

Tags: c++, templates, linkage, variable-templates

As [the doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) says (emphasis mine):

> Any of the following names declared at namespace scope have **internal linkage**:
>
> - non-volatile **non-template** non-inline **const-qualified variables** (including constexpr) that aren't declared extern and aren't previously declared to have external linkage;

So I'd expect const template variables to have external linkage. So I [did a test](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hAuNEvf8cf73yBTK):

```
// main.cpp
void other();

template<class T> T var = 1;
template<class T> const T constVar = 1;

int main() {
  std::cout << var<int> << ' ' << constVar<int> << std::endl;
  other();
}

// other.cpp
template<class T> T var = 2;
template<class T> const T constVar = 2;

void other() {
  std::cout << var<int> << ' ' << constVar<int> << std::endl;
}
```

And the output is:

```
1 1
1 2
```

The second column is for `constVar`, and it differs for different rows (printed from different translation units). This makes me think that it actually has internal linkage, despite being a template.

I understand that I do violate ODR, but only to understand what's happening.

So does `constVar` actually have internal linkage? If yes, what does the highlighted fragment of the doc mean? If no, then what's happening, and why do we need this highlighted fragment?

Comment: They are both templates, so the paragraph simply doesn't apply?

Comment: This looks more like an ODR violation (i.e. UB) than a linkage thing. But I don't really know anything about template variables so that might be wrong.

Comment: @Aconcagua exactly, but the behavior is like `constVar` has internal linkage, i.e. the paragraph seems to be applied

Comment: @Mikhail No, it looks like the compiler constant-folds the (allegedly) constant value into the output. You violate the one definition rule so you get undefined behavior.

Comment: @MaxLanghof ok, that's a reasonable explanation. I wonder what "non-template variable" means, though. There is no such thing as "template variable", there only is "variable template". We can use both, but the standard is careful about it. http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#5.2 says "non-template", and then http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#6.5 excludes templates again. Weird.

Comment: From related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335920/about-odr-violations-and-template-variables?rq=1

Comment: Try also printing `&constVar<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

[C++14 N4296 §14.4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

> A template name has linkage (3.5). [...] Template definitions shall obey the **one definition rule** (3.2).

[C++14 N4296 §3.2.6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

> Given
>   such an entity named D defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; [...]
>
> If D is a template and is defined in more than one translation unit, then the preceding requirements shall
>   apply both to names from the template’s enclosing scope used in the template definition (14.6.3), and also to
>   dependent names at the point of instantiation (14.6.2). If the definitions of D satisfy all these requirements,
>   then the behavior is as if there were a single definition of D. If the definitions of D do not satisfy these
>   requirements, then **the behavior is undefined**.

Templates are implicitly inline i.e. have external linkage.
What's happening = undefined behaviour.
Compiler is not required to diagnose your code and might produce unexpected/inconsistent results.

Comment: From the question: "I understand that I do violate ODR, but only to understand what's happening."

Comment: The question is about linkage. If the template has internal linkage, then two different templates are defined, not a template "defined in more than one translation unit", so the ODR would not apply.